# What is the equivalent of adding a jar to deployment assembly in maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, jar

I am working with a maven project in eclipse which I have been testing using the built-in "run on server" tomcat option. When I try to do this, I get errors stating certain dependencies are unmet from an external jar I reference in the POM. However I have found if I add the jar via the DeploymentAssembly Tab I can run in eclipse without issues:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.company.user.server.UserDetailsAuthoritiesMapper#0'
```

The issue comes when I try to deploy on an actual tomcat instance. The Maven build runs fine, but when I start the servlet I get the same unmet dependency errors. This to me is indicating that the external jar is not being properly packaged into the war. What is the maven equivalent of adding the package via the DeploymentAssembly tab in eclipse? The entry in the POM.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.company.webapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>webapp-user</artifactId>
    <version>106</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks

Comment: You may want to consider adding error messages and other snippets of information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to locate the maven info for the external jar. If you google the name of the jar and maven you often find a direct link to the block you need. For example if I want version 1.58 of the Bouncy castle jar Google "Maven BouncyCastle" you can find the artifact info. Add that info to your pom.xml as a new dependency in your  block.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.58</version>
</dependency>
```

After you rebuild, refresh maven in your IDE 1st after doing a clean, this will tell maven to pull down the jar and added it to your build.

You can also go to the repo directly and search:

**Maven Repo:** https://mvnrepository.com/

Comment: Right, in this case the jar is not managed by Maven, but a local jar that was built by another team. I have the packaged jar in the repo